# TypeORM leftJoinAndMapMany

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to build this query:

```
SELECT prize.*, account.*, raffle.*, COUNT(raffle_number.id) FROM raffle LEFT JOIN raffle_number ON raffle.id = raffle_number.raffle_id and raffle_number.state = '1' LEFT JOIN prize ON raffle.id = prize.raffle_id LEFT JOIN account ON raffle.owner_id = account.id GROUP BY raffle.id, prize.id, account.id ORDER BY raffle.created_at DESC;
```

with TypeORM, using postgresql.
The idea is that the raffle contains a count with the raffle_numbers that have certain state, but I need to fetch numbers first and then I will look into the where, lol.

I have come up with this:

```
raffleRep.createQueryBuilder('raffle').leftJoinAndMapMany('payedNumbers', 'raffle.numbers', 'raffle_number').leftJoinAndSelect('raffle.prizes', 'prizes').leftJoinAndSelect('raffle.owner', 'owner').where({title: Like(`${text}%`)}).groupBy('raffle.id, raffle_number.id, prizes.id, owner.id').orderBy('raffle.createdAt', 'DESC').skip(skip).take(take).getManyAndCount();
```

The thing is that is not mapping it. The property is there, I set it to type any, so I can debug and then set the type correctly.

I tried using `.select('COUNT('raffle_number.id')')` right after the createQueryBuilder but it gives me the error:

```
QueryFailedError: column distinctAlias.raffle_id does not exist
```

I could also use a raw query, but I would prefer not doing so.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the reason to "build" a query that already exists? Why not use it as raw? Obfuscation?

Comment: Not really, @Stefanov.sm. It's mainly to have the query return everything mapped to the properties

Comment: I understand, but you can do it nicely with parameterized query syntax. Why replace a clear and easy to read declarative statement with a smudgy sequence of cryptic imperative commands (i.e. method invocations)?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I ended up doing it raw and mapping the data myself. The thing is, my pagination does not really work. 
Since I get a record for every item in a relation, I can't use limit or offset, since that could consider a relation item as the ones I want to skip when, in reality, I want to skip only main records.
Because of this, I decided to process them all and then build a sub array based on the first one. What do you think?

Comment: Well, it might be better to use a `WITH` CTE instead of an array like `with t as (<the query for all items here>) select ... from t limit X offset Y`.